# Searching through index number in a .txt file (JSON format) in Python code

Tags: python, list, dictionary, indexing

I am a newbie to python and having some difficulties in programming. I have to search through the index number in a data.txt file and then delete the whole item according to the input of the user. My code is as follows:

```
    if option == 'd':
        if 'name' in open('data.txt').read():
            ind = int (input ("Menu item number to delete: "))
            with open ('data.txt') as data_file:
                data = json.load(data_file)
            if ind in data[ind]:
                del data[ind]
                json.dump(data, open('data.txt', 'w'))
                data_file.close()
                print ('Menu item deleted.\n')
            else:
                print ('No such items exist')
                main()
            main()
        else:
            print ('There are no menu items saved')
            main()
```

For e.g. if the user enters the 3, the 3rd item will be deleted. The code is working fine but I also have to find that whether the user entered index exists in the file or not and I am having errors in that through the command if ind in data[ind]: The error is shown below:

File "D:/R/043/N.py", line 41, in inputSomething
    if ind in data[ind]:
IndexError: list index out of range

Immediate help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

Based on the json you posted, you're loading an array rather than an object that's indexed by keys, so if you want to delete a specific item from the array, you would first need to check that it contains at least the number of items selected, then delete that item -- something like this:

EDIT: It is strange that you would expect your user to enter '0' for the first item in a menu, something like this would work:

```
        if len(data)-1 >= ind:
            del data[ind]
```

Comment: Doing this doesn't help as well. I already tried this and after this the code doesn't find the items which are already in the list

Comment: Are you able to post an excerpt of the json you're loading?

Comment: [
 {
 "name": "Big Mac",
 "calories": 540,
 "fat": 29,
 "protein": 25,
 "carbohydrates": 45,
 "sodium": 1040,
 "cholesterol": 75
 },
 {
 "name": "Whopper",
 "calories": 760,
 "fat": 47,
 "protein": 33,
 "carbohydrates": 53,
 "sodium": 1410,
 "cholesterol": 100
 },
 {
 "name": "Icecream",
 "calories": 760,
 "fat": 47,
 "protein": 33,
 "carbohydrates": 53,
 "sodium": 1410,
 "cholesterol": 100
 },
 {
 "name": "McDonald",
 "calories": 760,
 "fat": 47,
 "protein": 33,
 "carbohydrates": 53,
 "sodium": 1410,
 "cholesterol": 100
 }
]

Comment: It is working properly, except a single problem. Suppose I have 0,1,2 items in my dictionary and when I enter 3 it deletes the 2nd item, whereas, it should have printed that no such item exist.

Comment: The teacher has asked to reference the first element with '0'

Comment: It's updated based on what you requested -- but keep in mind, most users will not expect to enter '0' for the first element -- most programs will attempt to correct for this internally so the user can enter a '1', which is what most people would expect to do.... and does your teacher know you're getting answers to homework problems on stackoverflow ;)

Comment: Thanks that worked. I am unable to modify the requirements brother as the teacher has asked us to do the same.

Comment: It was a small problem though so my teacher won't mind probably. It won't be counted as plagiarism :-)